# Jupyter Notebook: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run the following code in jupyter Notebooks

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
```

and getting the following error

```
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1316                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1317                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1318             except OSError as err: # timeout error 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1243         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1244         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1245 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1289             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1290         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1291 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1238             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1239         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1240 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1025         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1026         self.send(msg)
   1027 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    965             if self.auto_open:
--> 966                 self.connect()
    967             else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in connect(self)
    937         self.sock = self._create_connection(
--> 938             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
    939         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    726     if err is not None:
--> 727         raise err
    728     else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    715                 sock.bind(source_address)
--> 716             sock.connect(sa)
    717             # Break explicitly a reference cycle

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I'm on a windows 10 machine with Anaconda {version: '4.7.12'}, python {version: '3.7.4'}

Is this related to HTTP Proxy ? I'm not sure how to configure it with jupyter notebooks. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're not alone. I'm getting a time out error too. I'm not using a proxy or jupyter so it probably is just that the source is down.

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
>>> mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
...
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Based on the discussion at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8588, it looks like this is a wider spread problem.

The following source works for me though.

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
>>> mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')
```